# How to resize QDockWidget

Tags: qt, resize, qdockwidget

I have created one application without centralwidget in my mainwindows, and shown as maximized:

```
setCentralWidget(0);
setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
```

In my mainwindow, I have three docks. The dock1 is set to be docked to leftDockWidgetArea, the dock2 and dock3 are set to be docked to the rightDockWidgetArea. Also, I arrange dock2 and dock3 by

```
splitDockWidget(ui->dock2, ui->dock3, Qt::Horizontal);
```

So I got a results that the ratio of the width of the three docks are [2:1:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqmW8.png).

My question is **how could I set the width of the three docks** so that they can be arranged as [1:4:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pidxi.png).

Suppose my screen's width is 1024. I have tried

```
ui->dockWidget_PrimeVis->resize(1000, 1000);
```

This does not work since I found some people say the size of docks are controlled by mainwindow. So I found I could call resizeDocks in mainwindow such as

```
resizeDocks({ ui->dock1, ui->dock2,ui->dock3}, { 150,600,150 }, Qt::Horizontal);
```

And it does not work. Also, since each dock contains one subclassed widget, I also tried to set the size to each subclassed widget, again, does not work.

Since we can manually change the size of each dock by GUI, so I believe there should be a way to set the size of each dock with codes, right? Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 3):

**The official [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#appearance) states the following:**

A `QDockWidget` acts as a wrapper for its child widget, set with `setWidget()`. Custom size hints, minimum and maximum sizes and size policies should be implemented in the child widget. `QDockWidget` will respect them, adjusting its own constraints to include the frame and title. Size constraints should not be set on the `QDockWidget`itself, because they change depending on whether it is docked; a docked `QDockWidget` has no frame and a smaller title bar.

**Solution:**

Just subclass the widget you are showing inside of the dockwidget. You can than overload different methods to change the size hint. For example: [QWidget.minimumSizeHint()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop)

**Not Tested:**

You could also just try to [set the minimum size](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop). But i do not know if this works.

Comment: Thank you Tim. However, I do not want to change the minumum size of the containing widgets. In other words, the dock1 dock2 and dock3 should all have the same minimum width 150. I assume there should be a way to directly change the geometry of the docks, right?